# How to call a Asynchronous function on button press using SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I have been learning Swift in Xcode playgrounds have successfully created some code to call a API that returns the latest currency conversion rates. To do this I had to use async and await to make sure the call to the API had completed before doing the conversion. I have now moved to creating a SwiftUI version to create a basic app that can take in a GBP value from the user, convert it to AED via the API call and then display the result to the user.

My problem is that when I run the app, enter the value to convert and press Convert nothing happens - it feels like I may have a problem with the Task call in the button action or something else is not correct. Any help is appreciated or pointers on basic design patterns to do this - for reference my code is here:

Exchange Swift Module:

```
//
//  Exchange.swift
//  CurrencyConvertorApp
//
//  Created by XXXXXX on 05/03/2023.
//
import Foundation

// MARK: - Information
struct Information: Codable {
    let success: Bool
    let query: Query
    let info: Info
    let date: String
    let result: Double
}

// MARK: - Info
struct Info: Codable {
    let timestamp: Int
    let rate: Double
}

// MARK: - Query
struct Query: Codable {
    let from, to: String
    let amount: Int
}

// MARK: - Code

let url = "https://api.apilayer.com/exchangerates_data/convert?to=AED&from=GBP&amount=1"
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)

func setUpRequest()
{
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue("MY KEY REMOVED", forHTTPHeaderField: "apikey")
}

func getExchangeValue(from request: URLRequest, to: String, from: String, amount: Double) async -> Double? {
    do {
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
        let information = try JSONDecoder().decode(Information.self, from: data)
        return amount * information.result
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
        return nil
    }
}

func buttonPressConvert (valueToConvert: Double) async -> Double?
{
    let exchange_value = await getExchangeValue(from: request, to:"GBP", from:"AED", amount: valueToConvert )
    return exchange_value
}
```

ContentView:

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  CurrencyConvertorApp
//
//  Created by XXXXXXXXX on 05/03/2023.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var GBPvalue = ""
    @State private var myString = ""
    @State private var myDouble = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack
        {
            Text("Currentcy Convertor App Version 0.1")
                .padding()
            Text("Beta Version")
    
            TextField("Enter GBP value here", text: $GBPvalue)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .padding()
            
            Button("Convert")
            {
                Task
                {   
                    let myDouble = Double(GBPvalue)
                    let exchangeResult = await getExchangeValue(from: request, to:"GBP", from:"AED", amount: myDouble ?? 0.0 )
                    let myString = String(exchangeResult ?? 0.0)
                }
            }
            
            Text(myString)
                .foregroundColor(.green)
                .font(.system(size: 60))
                .border(.green)
                .padding()
            
        }
        .padding()
        
        .onAppear()
        {
            setUpRequest()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: A couple of problems: 1) You're creating a *new* `myString` in the local scope within your task. You're not setting the existing `@State` variable. 2) Your `var request` likely shouldn't be declared in the global namespace (although it may work for now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach, where you create a `class ApiManager` and use it
to call the server. Note also your main problem (as mentioned in the comment @jnpdx),
the use of `self.myString = ...` in the Button Task.

```
// -- here
class ApiManager {
    
    let url = "https://api.apilayer.com/exchangerates_data/convert?to=AED&from=GBP&amount=1"
    let apikey = "YOUR_APIKEY"
    
    var request: URLRequest
    
    init() {
        self.request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!, timeoutInterval: 60.0)
        self.request.httpMethod = "GET"
        self.request.addValue(apikey, forHTTPHeaderField: "apikey")
    }
    
    func getExchangeValue(to: String, from: String, amount: Double) async -> Double? {
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
            let information = try JSONDecoder().decode(Information.self, from: data)
            return amount * information.result
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
            return nil  // <-- todo deal with errors
        }
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var GBPvalue = ""
    @State private var myString = ""
    @State private var myDouble = 0.0
    
    let apiManager = ApiManager() // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Currentcy Convertor App Version 0.1").padding()
            Text("Beta Version")
            
            TextField("Enter GBP value here", text: $GBPvalue)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .padding()
            
            Button("Convert"){
                Task {
                    if let myDouble = Double(GBPvalue),
                       let exchangeResult = await apiManager.getExchangeValue(to:"GBP", from:"AED", amount: myDouble) {
                        self.myString = String(exchangeResult)  // <-- here
                    } else {
                        self.myString = "error"  // <-- here
                    }
                }
            }
            Text(myString)
                .foregroundColor(.green)
                .font(.system(size: 60))
                .border(.green)
                .padding()
        }.padding()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: View structs shouldn't init objects, its a memory leak because View structs are constantly recreated and diffed.

Answer (score -2):

workingdog provides a good recommendation above in having the function and associated logic in a class, and making that accessible on the view.

When updating the view it is important to do this on the main actor / thread, otherwise you will get errors regarding background updates which can cause unstable results. Personally, I usually set a temporary results variable to collect the result in the Task, and when complete use MainActor.run to update the view, as in the below.

```
            Button("Convert"){
            Task {
                var result: String? = nil // <---- Local results vairable
                if let myDouble = Double(GBPvalue),
                   let exchangeResult = await apiManager.getExchangeValue(to:"GBP", from:"AED", amount: myDouble) {
                    result = String(exchangeResult)  // Set after success
                } else {
                    result = "error"  // Set if fails
                }
                
                if let result { // If a value us set update the view on the main actor
                    await MainActor.run(body: {
                        self.myString = result
                    })
                }
            }
        }
```